# generate n number of table rows depending on value of input jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

```
<input type="number" id="nostorey" name="" class=' InputBox' />

<table id="floor">
    <tr id="headtable">
        <td>
            <center>Floor Names</center>
        </td>
        <td>
            <center>Floor wise Area</center>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>1st Floor</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id="firstfloor" name='' maxlength="10" value="" class=' InputBox' />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>2nd Floor</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id="secondfloor" name='' maxlength="10" value="" class=' InputBox' />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>3rd Floor</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id="thirdfloor" name='' maxlength="10" value="" class=' InputBox' />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>4th Floor</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id="fourthfloor" name='' maxlength="10" value="" class=' InputBox' />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>Total</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id="total" readonly name='' maxlength="10" value="" class=' InputBoxD' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

  $("#nostorey").bind('change', function() {
  if ($.trim($(this).val()) < 5) {
    if ($(this).val().match(/^\d*$/)) {
      if ($(this).val() == 1) {
        console.log("1");
        console.log($(this).val());
        $('#secondfloor').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#thirdfloor').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#fourthfloor').prop('disabled', true);
      } else if ($(this).val() == 2) {
        console.log("2");
        console.log($(this).val());
        $('#secondfloor').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#thirdfloor').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#fourthfloor').prop('disabled', true);
      } else if ($(this).val() == 3) {
        console.log("3");
        console.log($(this).val());
        $('#secondfloor').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#thirdfloor').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#fourthfloor').prop('disabled', true);
      } else if ($(this).val() == 4) {
        console.log("4");
        console.log($(this).val());
        $('#secondfloor').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#thirdfloor').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#fourthfloor').prop('disabled', false);
      }
    }
  } else {
    var newItemHTML = '<tr><td ><span>' + $(this).val() + 'th Floor</span></td><td><input type="text" name="" class="InputBox " id="floor' + $(this).val() + '"></td></tr>';
    $("table#floor tr").last().before(newItemHTML);
  }
});
```

This is my code to tell how many floor I have in my input text by default I have 4 floors. `Onchange` of onstorey input I want to add the remaining floors currently what i did is to set if else but this is not working the way i want it because this way if I reduce the number of floor it is not reducing the number of input to write the area. I want to ask idea on how to make this possible

1. Make it in a way that when the number in storey input is more than 4 it will add the remaining floors.
2. When the number is reduced the number of input in the table should also decrease, but not less than the default value which is 4

   This is the [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/fq42seff/)

`UPDATED sample`
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/baegx3tr/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fq42seff/3/

i first added the `class="floor"` to all your floor input boxes, to have a unique selector for these input boxes. the entry field for the amount of floors and the total field is excluded.

then i changed your js the following:

```
//created two functions addFloors() and removeFloors()
function addFloors(actual, target){
  for(i = actual +1;i<=target;i++) //this loop creates the new floors
    {
      newItemHTML = '<tr><td ><p>' + i + 'th Floor</p></td><td><input type="text" name="" class="floor InputBox " id="floor' + i + '"></td></tr>';
      //i also changed the html inside the first td from <span> to <p> to match your html markup
      $("table#floor tr").last().before(newItemHTML);
    }
}

function removeFloors(target){
  if(target >= 4) //remove all floors except the base 4
  {
    $('.floor').slice(target).parent().parent().remove(); 
    //since i select the .floor input box, i have to use the parent() function two times, to move the selector up to the <tr> element
  }
}
```

next, we extend your change function:

```
$("#nostorey").bind('change', function() {
  curVal = $.trim($(this).val()).match(/^\d*$/); //get the value from the first input box
  curFloors = $('.floor').length; //get the current nbr of floors

if(curVal > curFloors)  //if you want more floors, then currently available
{
    addFloors(curFloors, curVal);  //add floors
}else if(curVal < curFloors)  //if you want less
{
    removeFloors(curVal);  //remnove them
}
```

last but not least, enable/disable the first 4 input boxes:

```
$('.floor').each(function(index){  //for each .floor input box
  if(index >= curVal)  //if it's index is greater then the needed floor count
  {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);  //disable it
  }else
  {
    $(this).prop('disabled', false);  //else enable it
  }
});
```

the last part - the enabling/disabling could be splitted and extend the add/remove functions - this would make them get run only when needed. right now, it gets executed on every value change. but i guess, you can figure out the rest by yourself...

Comment: Last question where did index in `$('.floor').each(function(index){` from and why use it

Comment: see http://api.jquery.com/each/ - each() generates the index by itself - since each() traverses through every matched element, we need to know, which element is currently in use - thats why we need and use the each index

Comment: cool you can also add an element. By element i and assuming it mean input checkbox or text box?

Comment: no, the each callback function gives you the current element, this does not mean, that you can add one. at least not with each() by itself.

Comment: i have a question why doesn't the generated input have an `onchange` event on them i tried putting on change event like this `$('.floor').change(function() {` the only responding input are the default ones but the generated on they dont do the `onchange` event is it natural or i have to set something up

Comment: if i got you right, you want to do something, after an input field value got changed. since event handlers are attached on dom load, dynamic generated fields don't have them. you need to use event delegation. in your case, this would be: $("#floor").on("change", "tr td .floor", function(){//do stuff here}); to get more information on that, head over to http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: i got it now i understand it :) happy coding

Comment: errand can i ask a question how can i put the span text as value for each respective input text i want to put it as hint like for example in input for `7th floor` i will add the `7th floor` as hint

Comment: you can select the content with .text(), given the right selector. and then set the title attribute of the input box with this value: .attr( "title", hintText ); see http://api.jquery.com/text/ and http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2

Comment: please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/baegx3tr/3/ the way it goes is like this when you enter number in the input box greater ex 6 it will add additional 2 columns for floors 5 and 6. the floors 1-4 checkbox has a value you can see them when you inspect element. I want to do here is when i generate new columns the checkboxes will also have value depending on which row they are in. Any idea will be appreciated `last update`

Comment: what i mean is i also want to add value to check box example in 5th floor row 1 value of checkbox should be `5th Floor Reinforced Concrete` in row 2 is `5th Floor Plain Cement` etc.

Comment: aah i see now ... first - use a class for the <td>'s that contain your description. 
you can set the value with the named .attr() function. to select the text from the span - you need do navigate to the element. e.g. if your selector is the current <td> where you insert the checkbox you will have to: .parent() to move up to the <tr> entry then use .find('classNameForSpan').text() to read the text out of the span...

Comment: when i do `var td = $("table#flooring tr").find('td:nth-child('+i+')');
        var value = td.parent().find('.floormaterialname').text();`the value of `value` will be all the span i want is one row only for for example in row one checkbox value of row one span only

Answer (score 0):

I added a grid of checkboxes depending on the number of floors also upon generating these checkboxes i put an attribute for each checkboxes depending on which row they are in. The span text or that row will be the value of the checkboxes for that row. With the help of

`Guruprasad Rao`

he came up with this fiddle

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/baegx3tr/6/)

For code betterment feel free to update the fiddle to help others

Answer (score -2):

Correct me if I am wrong. Here is my for loop.

```js
else {

var floors = parseInt($("#nostorey").val()-4); 

$("tr[id^=floor]").hide();

if(floors != NaN){

for(i=5;i<floors+5 ;i++){

    var newItemHTML = '<tr id="floor'+i+'"><td ><span>' + i + 'th Floor</span></td><td><input type="text" name="" class="InputBox floor"' + i + '"></td></tr>';

    $("table#floor tr").last().before(newItemHTML);
}

}
```