# selector for checkbox with nextall jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Using the code below...

```
$("table#flooring tr")
.find('td:eq('+checkbox+') input[type="checkbox"]')
.prop('disabled', true);
```

...this is how I disable a checkbox based on the td it is in the variable `checkbox` for index is dynamic depending on user input. How would it look if i change it to selecting all checkbox after the current one i tried

```
$("table#flooring tr")
.find('td:eq('+checkbox+') input[type="checkbox"]')
.nextAll()
.prop('disabled', true);
```

But it is not disabling the checkbox

Any idea is appreciated. Markup is as follow:

```
<table id="flooring">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <strong>
                <p>Flooring</p>
            </strong>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <hr/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>1st Floor</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>2nd Floor</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>3rd Floor</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>4th Floor</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>Reinforced Concrete</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="floor1st checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="floor2nd checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="loor3rd checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="floor4th checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>Plain Cement</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="floor1st checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="floor2nd checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="floor3rd checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="floor4th checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>Marble</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="floor1st checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="floor2nd checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="floor3rd checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="floor4th checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>Wood</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="floor1st checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="floor2nd checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="floor3rd checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="floor4th checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>Tiles</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="floor1st checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="floor2nd checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="floor3rd checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="floor4th checkboxfloor" name="flooring[]" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you share the html and the value of `checkbox` variable

Comment: do you mean current one in the row or in the entire table

Comment: in the row only wait let me post the html what do you mean by checkbox variable?

Comment: it could be `$("table#flooring tr").find('td:eq('+checkbox+')').nextAll().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('disabled', true);` if the checkboxes are in the same row

Comment: yeah same row..but many rows but same number of td for each row

Comment: that is the more appropriate selector you can post it as an answer some people might need that.

Comment: now where is your script `$("table#flooring tr").find('td:eq('+checkbox+') input[type="checkbox"]').nextAll().prop('disabled', true);` placed and what are you looking for..

Comment: Assuming I'm clicking on `Marble + 2nd Floor ` what should happen

Comment: In the project i need to select number of storey for building so after input of number of storey i should generate number of floor, i have a default of 4 floors if the input is below 4 then i will disable n number of floors depending on user input. its looking good now all i need to do now is to be able to check the check box based on values from database for example if in database the material for 2nd floor is marble and wood i should tick the two checkbox..

Comment: Where is the `checkbox` variable defined? Please share the relevant code.

Comment: It is working now sir @Terry the selector i used was wrong it should be the way  sir arun suggested it was perfect i am able to select all checkbox of the next td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
var floor = +this.value; //where floor is the number of floors
var $chcks = $('#flooring input[type="checkbox"]');
if (floor) {
    var $enabled = $('#flooring tr').find('td:lt(' + (floor + 1) + ')').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true).prop('disabled', false);
    $chcks.not($enabled).prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uygm2L62/)

Comment: How to put event delegation for find? for example i want to add new row below for material. I tried adding already but if the checkbox is disable after adding it is enable meaning i need to use event delegation right?i need to make the new checkbox with same td notice that the checkbox should be disabled. I searched but so far i only see `.on ( click`

Comment: @HogRider you can't do that... you need to disable/check it while adding the element

Comment: can you give sample can you use the fiddle you have and add another row named other material then depending on floor disabled the added checkbox also will enable or disable?

Comment: @HogRider if you can edit the fiddle to create a new row and show what you are trying I can try to have a look

Comment: this the fiddle i made http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/uygm2L62/3/ the scenario is you add storey first then click the add button

Comment: arun check this out i made it like this `enabled = $("#flooring tr:eq(2)").find('td').find('.floor:enabled').length;` then i pass it to the function that enables and disable the checkbox and its ok now

Comment: can you check the fiddle and show me how to add dynamic row not like the way i did it static i mean it will always be 4 what if i want to add more

Comment: can you check this question of mine check the update maybe you can help me..if you inspect the element of each check from column 1-4 they have value after generating addiotional column i want to have the same value for each checkbox this is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29116620/generate-n-number-of-table-rows-depending-on-value-of-input-jquery