# generated check box will find the value of the first td in the row it is in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, uitableview

In my project i am adding a td with checkbox inside of the td. I autogenerate it based on a certain criteria. I would like to get the value of the first td of the row the autogenerated checkbox is in.

So i would like to know how to do this. I havent got any idea in how to do so i dont have a code to show.

My idea for now is to get the index of the row where the generated checkbox is in and use that index as selector for `:eq(index)`. I am still working on this one because i have not yet got the index.

Hoping for constructive comments

Comment: how you are adding `td`?? dynamically??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ukpp5z3n/1/)**

```
$('.chk').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).parent('td').siblings('td:first').text());
});
```

Check this **[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ukpp5z3n/2/)**. I have added multiple rows with and without checkbox!

Comment: yes something like this one i have one question i am generating many row row but in my checkbox the only value they get is the first row not the row they belong to. but this is what i am trying to do only difference is i need to get the value of first td of the row they are in. not the first row only. i hope i am making sense.

Comment: I have kept 2 rows in the demo!! It will get the value of first td of the row wherever the checkbox is!! Did you try that?? Check the updated demo!

Comment: sure!! take your time.. :)

Comment: i think i can make this work i will find a way to make it work i hope you are willing to entertain if i have question. This is the closest thing to what i want

Comment: Yea!! anytime!!.. Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao please check my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29116620/generate-n-number-of-table-rows-depending-on-value-of-input-jquery/29117847?noredirect=1#comment48435044_29117847 i have same problem. My problem is when generating new checkbox i want to add value to checkbox depeding on which row it is in

Comment: @HogRider. You already have an accepted answer to your question! What is the problem you are facing now?

Comment: can you check the updated fiddle in the fiddle i want to add a value to generated checkbox by default i have 4 columns of checkbox when i change the number in text box it will generate same number of columns but i can get the respective text for the span where the checkbox belong for example the checkbox is in row 1 the value should be the text in span for row.

Comment: if you want i can post a different question so you can post you own answer it is a bit different anyway from that question i added it there because they are related to each other

Comment: Let me check and will get back to you!!

Comment: @HogRider. Bit confused here! Can you elaborate bit more!! From the things you explained what I understood is _You will add checkbox based on the number entered in the input. Now for example say I've entered 10 in `textbox` and I'll get 10 textboxes + 10 columns in the table! Now when I click any `checkbox` what should happen? It should get the `row span text` and add it in particular textbox_??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao there should be an attribute value in the check because i am going to use that attribute later on..the value will be the value of span so for example column 5 row 1 checkbox will be value `Reinforced Concrete` row 2 will be `Plain Cement` and so on i hope i am clear.. if you check column 1-4 has value i am hoping it will continue until the last column

Comment: @GuruprasadRao for your question it should make the text of the row span as the value of the checkbox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77689/discussion-between-guruprasad-rao-and-hogrider).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the checkbox td's parent tr element, then get the first tr child element of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest), [.find](http://api.jquery.com/find), and [.first](http://api.jquery.com/first)

```
checkbox.closest("tr").find("td").first();
```

1. `closest` finds the closest parent element matching the selector
2. `find` searches the element for the matching selector
3. `first` returns the first element.

You could also shorten it to

```
checkbox.closest("tr").find("td:first")
```

Selector `:first` does the same thing as the function, it matches the first element in the set.

Demo

```js
var checkbox = jQuery("#mycheckbox");
var firstTD = checkbox.closest("tr").find("td").first();
jQuery("#log").text( "First TD: "+firstTD.text() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>

<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Test</td>
         <td>Test 2</td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" /></td>
         <td>Test 3</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**JSFIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/fbpc0jqd/

You can search for the checkbox using jquery selectors such as:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]')
```

Then you can use the following to get the text of the first td in the current row:

```
.parents().closest('tr').children('td:first-child').text()
```